# Converting linux commands to URI/CGI encoded. A better way?

Tags: cgi, urlencode, kali-linux

I am testing some PHP apps for injectable commands.  I have to convert my commands to a URI/CGI encoded format.  I am wondering if there is a better way to do it.

When I want to include a ping (to test if the app is, in fact, executing from an injection) I am converting it as follows.

```
hURL -X --esc ";ping localhost -c 1" | sed -e ‘s/\\x/\%/g’
```

Here is the output.

```
%3b%20%70%69%6e%67%20%6c%6f%63%61%6c%68%6f%73%74%20%2d%63%20%31
```

Works perfect.  The code is injected and logs are showing it being handled as expected.

*QUESTION:*  Is there a better way to convert to the above.  I think I am over complicating things.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly use an out-of-the-box library for doing the escaping, may be a little easier on the eye ...

```
$ echo ';ping localhost -c 1' | perl -ne 'use URI::Escape; print(uri_escape($_) . "\n");'                                                                                                              
%3Bping%20localhost%20-c%201%0A
```

Obviously this output does not escape legitimate url chars so not sure this entirely answers your question ...

Comment: Interesting, however it adds significant complexity, potential for errors as you need to sanitize the text before encoding.  That being said I really appreciate the different approach.  It is the kind of thought I am looking for.